# "bei mir" or "mir" (ist alles klar)

Tags: preposition

There is one topic which is not clear for me. Which one should I say:

"Bei mir ist alles klar"

or

"Mir ist alles klar"

Is there any difference between them? Can you please explain?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends what you want to express, you probably want the latter, "Mir ist alles klar".

> Mir ist alles klar

Everything is clear to me

> Bei mir ist alles klar

This does not refer to your understanding but the state of things. It will rather be understood along the lines of "everything is ok here" or "everything ready" or even "everyone / I ready".

Comment: I don't agree with the statement "This is uncommon", there are situations where this sentence is a completely natural response, e.g. to a question like "Sind alle bereit?" ("Is everybody ready?").

Comment: You are right, given that context

Comment: thank you for your answers! mir ist alles klar :)